# Проверка на четность строки типа wchar_t

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, wchar-t

Нужно проверить на четность строку типа wchar_t и добавить в конце символ если она не четная. Но при работе выдает, что размерность буферного массива должна быть константой, задаю ее как константу, но все равно вылезает та же ошибка. Пример кода:

```
if (Message_Len % 2 != 0 )
    {
      const int Len = Message_Len+1;      
      wchar_t Buff[Len];
      for(int k = 0;k < Len;k++)
        Buff[k] = Message_Text[k];
      Buff[Len] = Buff[Message_Len];
      Buff[Message_Len] = '_';
      for (int k = 0; k < Len; k++)
           Message_Text[k]= Buff[k];
    }
```

Comment: Для строк понятие чётности - не определено.

Comment: Думаю четная строка это стркоа с четным количеством символов. в с++ нельзя создавать динамический массивы во время выполнения `wchar_t Buff[Len];` пишите так `wchar_t *Buff = new wchar_t[Len];` и потом не забудьте удалить `delete[] Buff;`

Comment: @goldstar_labs А у меня вопрос, если `Message_Text` задан константным выражением, вот так: `wchar_t Message_Text[] =  L"МОВА_ПАЙТОН_ЗМЕНШУЄ_ЗАГАЛЬНУ_ВАРТІСТЬ_ЕКСПЛУАТАЦІІ_ПРОГРАМИ:";` То я не могу же добавлять в него символы, мне надо задать его динамически тоже?

Comment: Объект объявленный как `const int` может являться константным выражением в том и только в том случае, если он инициализирован константным выражением. У вас это правило нарушено. Ничего подобного вы в С++ сделать вот именно так не сможете. В С++ размер нединамического массива должен быть задан во время компиляции - без вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

Если  `Message_Len` не является  константным выражением, то во время выполнения  обьект  `Len`  может принимать разные значения, так как вы инициализровали:  `const int Len = Message_Len+1;`, т.е.  значение зависит от значения другого. А создавать массив, чей размер не является константным выражением, в C++ невозможно. Другое дело, если  константный обьект инициализировать константным выражением, например:

```
const int Len = 10; //или любым другим константным выражением
```

Иначе нужно создать динамический массив или пользоваться услугами какого то контейнера(стандартного или самописного).

**P.S.**
Если `Message_Len` является размером массива некоторого строкового массива `Message`, имеющий конкретный размер, то вы в любой момент можете инициализировать любой элемент символом конца строки `'\0'`, тогда размер строки изменится.  Константным выражением будет лишь размер занимаемой памяти, т.е. `sizeof(Message)`, но никак не размер строки `strlen(Message)`. То же самое касается любым другим типам.